# Is there a way to author a SQL query from inside Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-data-factory

Trying to find a way to author SQL queries from inside of ADF, is this possible or would a view need to be created to do something similar?

Comment: Is `SELECT * FROM TABLE` authoring a SQL query? You can type that straight into a number of areas in Azure Data Factory. Your question is very broad. Which part of ADF?

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , we can depending upon what is that you are trying to achieve , copy activity,  lookup activity are few examples

Answer (score 0):

Most of time, yes you can author SQL queries from inside of ADF.

For SQL server and Azure SQL database, copy data from or to SQL server or Azure SQL database support you use the SQL query to select the data.

For example, using 'Copy Data' to copy data between Azure SQL:
[image]

**But these SQL queries are used for Source dataset settings**.

There are a lot examples can help you understand Azure Data Factory Copy Actives.

Such as: [Copy Data From On-Premise SQL Server To Azure Database Using Azure Data Factory](https://marlonribunal.com/copy-data-from-on-premise-sql-server-to-azure-database-using-azure-data-factory/).

I suggest you read more about [Azure Data Factory Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/). You will have the answer more clearly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with "author SQL queries".

If you want to write sql queries based on input from other activities and execute them you can do this by using dynamic content (click on "add dynamic content" on the query field where you want to execute the sql query, e.g. in copy data or lookup)

If you want to run sql code on a data source from a data factory e.g. to create a table there you can use the lookup activity and just add a ;select 1; in the end. e.g.

```
Select * into newtable from oldtable; select 1;
```

Also you could use a stored procedure on a data source e.g. azure sql or sql server and provide properties from data factory.

For all this best to create a dataset where you leave the "table" property empty and use this.